# Source not found when open Java Imported Class on Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse

I have some problem to open the class inside my project libraries on Eclipse Luna. For the beginning I have .war file of my web apps, I imported that .war files to Eclipse Luna and I could open index.jps files and other files under Web Content folder. But when I'm tried to open the engine class file I got Source not found. This is the screenshot of the errors.

[image]

I'm new in Java code and with Eclipse. What's wrong with that errors and how to resolve that problems ? Please anybody knows could help me. Thanks before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAR files don't usually contain the Java source code, just the compiled class files which is what you are seeing.

If you have the Java source elsewhere you can use the 'Attach Source...' button shown in that screenshot to tell Eclipse about it.

Comment: How if I just have WAR files only ?

Comment: @Antonio As I said war files don't contain the source so there is nothing you can do except try a Java decompiler.

Comment: @Antonio you can do a reverse engineering in order to extract war files codes 
its easy

Comment: @Antonio please take a look at the following decompiler http://www.javadecompilers.com/

Comment: @BasilBattikhi I tried to decompile the WAR files but I got `Oh snap! Please, select APK decompiler to decompile .apk and .dex files.` that errors.